# Do the Enlarge and Shrink spells only really affect damage and AC, or do they do more?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

From what I've seen, Enlarge and Shrink modify strength, dex, AC, to hit and damage roll, but strength and attack roll modifications even out. Thus is AC and damage the only things affected by those two spells?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, yes. *Enlarge Person* gives you more damage and reach and less AC while *Reduce Person* gives you less damage and more AC.

There are a handful of uses outside combat for these spells but they don't come up often.

With *Enlarge Person* your Carrying Capacity gets a huge boost (2x normal in most cases), in the case of Strength focused characters this can push your heavy load into multiple tons.

With *Reduce Person* you get a +4 bonus on a number of skills like escape artist and stealth. In addition you're half as tall and weigh half as much, allowing you to perform a wide variety of shenegains like hiding in a party member's rucksack or escaping a noose.

Comment: Noose, manacles, ropes, basically most restraints!

Comment: Nooses are generally used for hanging, maybe pulling, in which case they would tighten around the smaller neck due to the pull on the rope (either by gravity or a slaver's hand). Indirectly Reduce Person might free hands which let you deal with the noose, but unless the noose is not being pulled it would not be directly effected by the spell.

Answer (score 5):

Beyond the points mentioned in the spell (such as reach for large humanoids, or the difference for dex based attacks vs strength based attacks, and obviously dex and str based skill checks) size effects

1. Smaller creatures get a bonus to Stealth checks, while larger creatures get a penalty. Larger creatures have more Vertical Reach when Jumping, the Pathfinder SRD doesn't really talk about it like the 3.5 does, but it's not like it replaces it with anything. Disguise Checks get a penalty if you're trying to disguise yourself as somebody of a different size, so Enlarge and Shrink Person can be used to more effectively disguise yourself as an Ogre or halfling. Intimidate gets a bonus if you're larger than the target, and a penalty if you're smaller. Possibly other skills get changes I didn't notice.
2. Combat Maneuver Bonus gets higher as you get higher, which stacks with the str bonus, of Enlarge Person, while the penalty stacks with the str penalty of Shrink Person, while Combat Maneuver Defense gets a bonus as you get larger, but benefits from strength and dex, which will even out, leaving you with just the bonus or penalty from size either way.
3. Carry Capacity gets larger when you get larger and vice versa.
4. Smaller creatures can squeeze through smaller spaces, while Larger creatures are more limited in what they can squeeze through.
5. Tiny Creatures (so a halfling effected by reduce person) use different rules for reach and moving through opponents squares, while Large and larger creatures take up more space on the battle field. [Details.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Creature-Size-and-Scale)

And of course just your physical size and weight changing is going to effect the way you interact with the world in certain ways small, such as with boats, or other people or mounts carrying you, or many other small changes that won't necessarily come up if you're happen to be fighting an Orc guarding a chest.

Comment: isnt the CMB cancelled out by the base attack modifications in the spells?

Comment: No, CMB is based only on STR so it changes with your size. CMD is based on STR+DEX+Size. So the STR & DEX generally cancel each other out, but the size still applies.

Answer (score 4):

You also get an increased reach with melee weapons.

What's often overlooked, ironically, in these spells is that they make you taller/shorter and heavier/lighter, which are all very useful in certain situations. Don't just look at the core stat-based effects unless you only care about combat.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that these spells change the target's size.

Comment: +1 Reach is a big (pun intended) factor for fighters, very important consideration for enlarge!

Answer (score 2):

If you are a strength based character concerned only about melee weapon combat, yes.

However, if you:

- Use a Dexterity based weapon
- Need to make use of Strength independent of combat
- Need to make use of Dexterity independent of combat

Then that is not the case. Dexterity and Strength are used in far more than just basic combat.

Answer (score 2):

Height and weight have tons of implications outside of combat.

My favorite use of the enlarge spell came when we found a 700lbs artifact that nobody could carry out of the dungeon and onto the horses cart.  Solution was an enlarged barbarian trying to run through a dungeon carrying a 700lbs slab before he shrank back down.